# Cannot import name 'available_if' from 'sklearn.utils.metaestimators'

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, imbalanced-data, imblearn, smote

While importing "from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE", getting import error. Please check and help.
I tried upgrading sklearn, but the upgrade was undone with 'OSError'.
Firsty installed imbalance-learn through pip.

```
!pip install -U imbalanced-learn
```

- Using jupyter notebook
- Windows 10
- sklearn version - 0.24.1
- numpy version - 1.19.5

  ```
   --------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
  ```

  in 
  ----> 1 from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE

  ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\imblearn_*init*_.py in 
  35 import types
  36
  ---> 37 from . import combine
  38 from . import ensemble
  39 from . import exceptions

  ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\imblearn\combine_*init*_.py in 
  3 """
  4
  ----> 5 from ._smote_enn import SMOTEENN
  6 from ._smote_tomek import SMOTETomek
  7

  ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\imblearn\combine_smote_enn.py in 
  8 from sklearn.utils import check_X_y
  9
  ---> 10 from ..base import BaseSampler
  11 from ..over_sampling import SMOTE
  12 from ..over_sampling.base import BaseOverSampler

  ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\imblearn\base.py in 
  13 from sklearn.utils.multiclass import check_classification_targets
  14
  ---> 15 from .utils import check_sampling_strategy, check_target_type
  16 from .utils._validation import ArraysTransformer
  17 from .utils._validation import _deprecate_positional_args

  ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\imblearn\utils_*init*_.py in 
  5 from ._docstring import Substitution
  6
  ----> 7 from ._validation import check_neighbors_object
  8 from ._validation import check_target_type
  9 from ._validation import check_sampling_strategy

  ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\imblearn\utils_validation.py in 
  14 from sklearn.base import clone
  15 from sklearn.neighbors._base import KNeighborsMixin
  ---> 16 from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors
  17 from sklearn.utils import column_or_1d
  18 from sklearn.utils.multiclass import type_of_target

  ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\neighbors_*init*_.py in 
  14 from ._nearest_centroid import NearestCentroid
  15 from ._kde import KernelDensity
  ---> 16 from ._lof import LocalOutlierFactor
  17 from ._nca import NeighborhoodComponentsAnalysis
  18 from ._base import VALID_METRICS, VALID_METRICS_SPARSE

  ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\neighbors_lof.py in 
  10 from ..base import OutlierMixin
  11
  ---> 12 from ..utils.metaestimators import available_if
  13 from ..utils.validation import check_is_fitted
  14 from ..utils import check_array

  ImportError: cannot import name 'available_if' from 'sklearn.utils.metaestimators'
  (C:\Users\dks_m\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\metaestimators.py)

Answer (score 10):

IF in jupyter , restart the kernel.This fixed!

Answer (score 3):

I believe the issue is with python versioning of scikit-learn. I was able to resolve by reinstalling the Python3 version:

```
pip uninstall scikit-learn -y

pip3 install scikit-learn
```

*Remember to restart terminal/notebook after package updates.*

This gives me `scikit-learn v1.0.2` which resolves error in Python3

Answer (score 0):

Try using anaconda prompt for installation.
It works for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

That usually happens when 2 different versions of packages do not match. If you are using the jupyter notebook, restarting your environment is going to solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Good day all. What helped me is installing pycaret=='2.3.10 ' and scikit-learn='0.23.2' at the same time. These two version are compatible and all works fine. I installed scikit-learn using conda as the older versions are not available through pip, and I installed Pycaret using pip3. I hope this helps all who have struggled to get this working like I did.

Answer (score 0):

If using **databricks** :
Go-to: `view` -> `view spark ui` -> `Libraries` -> `install new` -> `Library Source` -> `PyPi` -> add package name : `imbalanced-learn` -> `install` ->
`Restart the cluster`

// Do not install from active notebook using cli command.

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading the sklearn did the job for me

```
pip install scikit-learn==1.2.0
```